# Diode as switch

Tags: diodes, switches

I am trying to prove/disprove the concept. I hear that a diode could be used to switch low power analog signals. The idea is this:

In this case the diode is reverse biased, so it is off and the signal does not pass thru it.

[image: Text]

In this case the diode is forward biased, so the analog signal will pass thru.

[image: Text]

So, I built the circuit. I use a 300 Hz, 1 V sine as source and oscilloscope to view the output signal. What happens in reality is the signal does pass in both cases, since the GND-VCC circuit conducts too -- whatever it is: a microcontroller, a PSU or anything else. Even if I use a bare battery with a 4.7k resistor to apply forward/reverse voltage directly to the diode, the circuit does pass signal even when the diode IS reverse-biased.

Does that mean this circuit is a hoax? Or, is there a correct way to do it?

p.s. It sort of does work if I DC offset the input signal relative to the diode without applying voltage to the diode. But this has to be done with an isolated current source which sort of renders the whole idea pointless.

Comment: Your schematics are missing the component values and the input impedance of your oscilloscope or whatever you're using to measure.

Comment: The resistors are 4.7k each and the capacitors are 0.68uF each. Oscilloscope is using a probe with a 1:10 divider so the impedance should be infinite.

Comment: But what is the amplitude of the signal before and after it goes through the diode? Do you notice any phase shifts?

Comment: No, it looks the same. The concept sort of does work. When the diode is forward biased, the sine passes thru unchanged. Same amplitude and shape as input. However, there is no way to reverse bias the diode without leaking the signal. That's the problem.

Comment: As a diagnostic (to check for trouble with the setup), try removing the diode altogether and measure how much signal still leaks through. If you're using solderless breadboard, that may have significant parasitic capacitive coupling between rows.

Comment: I’ve seen this technique used - mainly in RF. For switching audio signals, devices like jfets or cmos bilateral switches are normally used. Nevertheless, it is a circuit technique that can be useful in specific cases if the limitations are understood. Kudos to investigating it. One day you might need it and lesser engineers will elevate your status to ‘analog guru’!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzDzKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Top - biased off. Bottom - biased on.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The CircuitLab simulator results. Blue = Node1. Orange = Node2. Brown = Node3.*

It looks like it works. The NODE3 voltage will decay over time given by C4 × R8.